# Illustrator - Maintaining Coordinates when exporting Layers as SVG's

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, svg

I made a very simple house in **Illustrator**, placing each of it's elements in it's own independent layer as follows:

1. Door
2. Windows
3. Roof
4. House

[image]

I then used **Illustrator's** **"Asset Export"** to export all these layers as individual SVG's - so I could then import and re-compose them back together as my House  image on a web-page. (I intend to create multiple variations of the house - using javascript - by tweaking each of the individual SVG's.)

The exporting works - but the importing doesn't: the spacing, coloring, and scaling of the SVG's is off.

Here's what I get when I combine just the "house" and "roof" SVG's:

[image]

First off, the positioning of the **Roof** SVG is way off: instead of being on top of the **House**, it's *inside* it.
Second, the **House** SVG doesn't maintain its yellow color, instead, it "inherits" its color from the **Roof** SVG, so that they're BOTH Blue.

I'm assuming the problem lies with the way I'm combining the `SVG` tags in my `HTML`.

Here's the `SVG` file **Illustrator** created for the **House** layer when I exported it using "Asset Export":

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 130 151">
  <defs>
    <style>
       .cls-1{fill:#fff800;}.cls-2{fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}.
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
    <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
      <rect class="cls-1" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="129" height="150"/>
      <rect class="cls-2" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="129" height="150"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

And here's the `SVG` it created for the **Roof** layer when I exported it using "Asset Export":

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 190.8 75">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1{fill:#1f00ff;}
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
    <g id="Layer_2-2" data-name="Layer 2">
      <polygon class="cls-1" points="190.8 75 0 75 95.4 0 190.8 75"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

In my `HTML` and `Javascript` code I basically just concatenated the two SVG's together as one string variable and assigned it as the `innerHTML` of a `<div>` I created to display the house - and that didn't work. I also tried different variations of that - nothing's doing it right.

So my question is obviously: what's the right way to do you this? How do I combine the code of the different SVG's to compose the house back together the proper way?
Or is there a specific way I'm supposed to export the layers out of **Illustrator** as SVG's so they can come back together correctly?

Comment: I believe you'd need to set a viewbox with the same dimensions for every piece. In AI terms.. a no fill, no stroke rectangle that is exported with every part.

Comment: ok I'll try that. But what about the colors? Why is the color of one SVG overriding the colors of all the other ones?

Comment: Because the CSS declaration is the same.. and CSS *cascades*, honoring the last properties set for an element. i.e..... change "the `class` so they are *different* in all the images.

Comment: of course - different class names - that makes sense. I didn't notice they named all the classes the same. Gotta say, I'm surprised AI doesn't take care of this for you - I mean you're exporting a bunch of *different* assets at the same time, why doesn't it recognize this? Why is it giving each one of these *different* assets the same class name?

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a better tool out there to do this exporting of multiple layers? Something that's more "intelligent"? Cause I'm looking at exporting possibly 200+ layers - there'd be a lot of manual work to "fix" all the problems AI is not taking care of here...